# PHP MailSo library and attachments

Tags: php, email, mime, mime-message, mime-mail

I'm trying to use [MailSo](https://github.com/detochko/MailSo) library to create MIME message. I have got to the point where next step is to process attachments. Everything is fine when attachments are binary files but when I try to to add plain text attachment as follow

```
$rResource = "Some plain text goes here";
$sFileName = 'text.txt';
$iFileSize = \strlen("Some plain text goes here");
$bIsInline = false;
$bIsLinked = false;
$sCID = $metadataCID;
$aCustomContentTypeParams = array(\MailSo\Base\Enumerations\Encoding::QUOTED_PRINTABLE_LOWER);

$oMessage->Attachments()->Add(
    \MailSo\Mime\Attachment::NewInstance(
        $rResource,
        $sFileName,
        $iFileSize,
        $bIsInline,
        $bIsLinked,
        $sCID,
        $aCustomContentTypeParams
    )
);
```

I expect to see that attachment as

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=text.txt
```

but it always forcing to base64 neither adding charset to content-type part as

```
Content-Type: text/plain; name="text.txt" 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.txt" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MailSo library treats all attachments except `message/rfc822` as binaries. It will require to rewrite or extend `createNewMessageAttachmentBody()` private function.